# Does BOOST asio supports eventfd? like epoll

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

[epoll()](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) can do its poll on lots of fd types such as normal fd, sockets, timefd, eventfd, etc...

Can BOOST do it also somehow?
I saw in [io_service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) that it supports only:

> The io_service class provides the core I/O functionality for users of
> the asynchronous I/O objects, including:
>
> boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
> boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor
> boost::asio::ip::udp::socket
> deadline_timer.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation describes some, but not all, of the things the `io_service` class can do. Note the that it says "including", not "only". Also, the next sentence in the documentation reads:

```
The io_service class also includes facilities intended for developers of custom asynchronous services.
```

If you are reading or writing to a file descriptor that you have created directly, you can use `boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor`. You can use the `serial_port` classes. You can operate on files. I think you'll be able to map your operation; if you still have trouble ask a more specific question.